# Use PowerBI Embedded in PHP

Tags: php, azure, powerbi-embedded

I am new to Power BI embedded and have gone through several tutorials but all I could get was tutorial on embedding it in C#, but I'm a php developer and have no idea of C#.

I have created my Power BI report and generated the tokens by registering a new Power BI in my Azure portal.

How do I now use these tokens?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of steps you need to take:

1. Create a Workspace Collection inside Azure and get the Access keys (I understand you've completed this)
2. Create a Workspace using the [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt711503.aspx) - with PHP, you'll be using probably use CURL for this. Don't forget to add the Authorization header with one of the Access keys and use POST as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-iframe/). Note that you don't need to actually post anything, just use the POST method, otherwise you'll just get a JSON with the existing workspaces.

   `POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/collections/mypbiapp/workspaces
   Authorization: AppKey {yourAccessKey}`

Now you should have a workspace id.

3. Import a .pbix file from Power BI Desktop into your workspace. This is [also achieved using the REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt711504.aspx). **don't forget to add the datasetDisplayName parameter to the URL**, ie: POST the data and file to 

   `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/collections/{collectionName}/workspaces/{workspaceId}/imports?datasetDisplayName={somename}`

Now you should have a report id.

4. Create an embed token. This is a JSON Web Token (JWT). You can use [php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) for this. The JWT claims payload required for PBIe are listed [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-app-token-flow/). Note that you only need to pass the payload and your Access key to php-jwt.
5. With that token, you can finally embed the report in your application using [PowerBI Javascript](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript). You can just copy the powerbi.js file from the dist dir if you wish. You need to create a configuration object as [described here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding-Basics).

   `var embedConfiguration = {
   type: 'report',
   accessToken: {your-jwt-token-string},
   id: {your-report-id-string},
   embedUrl: 'https://embedded.powerbi.com/appTokenReportEmbed'
   };
   var $reportContainer = $('#reportContainer'); //some div
   var report = powerbi.embed($reportContainer.get(0), embedConfiguration);`

And now you should have a report in your app.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the basic iframe solution which works for me for many use cases.

Following are the steps:

1. Open the Report you need to embed
2. Click File Menu on the left top
3. Click publish to web
4. Click embed code
5. Click Publish
6. Select the html code and place it in your web application